# compare an image using ImageMagick and only get result true/false 0/1

Tags: compare, imagemagick

We use a `git` repo for screenshots and always the images are marked changed by `git`, but with apply fuzz, there are no changes.

I use this script to compare images

```
do_compare()
{
     compare $color_flag $fuzz_flag $backgroundcolor_flag "$f1" "$f2" png:- | \
        montage -geometry +4+4 $backgroundcolor_flag "$f1" - "$f2" png:- >"$destfile" 2>/dev/null || true
}
```

but I want only know if there is a change in the image, with respect the **fuzz**, or not.

Does someone has an idea how to do so ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that in command line ImageMagick on Unix using

```
compare -metric ae -fuzz XX% image1 image2 null: 2>&1
```

`-metric ae` will return the number of pixels that do not match. So if the result is 0, then it matches perfectly within the specified -fuzz value.

For example, testing with fuzz = 0:

```
XX=0
test=`compare -metric ae -fuzz $XX% lena.png lena.jpg null: 2>&1`
if [ "$test" = "0" ]; then
echo "match"
else
echo "no match"
fi

no match
```

Testing with fuzz = 10%:

```
XX=10
test=`compare -metric ae -fuzz $XX% lena.png lena.jpg null: 2>&1`
if [ "$test" = "0" ]; then
echo "match"
else
echo "no match"
fi

match
```

Comment: It works but for some reason, I can't get the output in the variable. It prints the value with a % appended (zsh) and the variable stays empty. I tried with backticks and "$()" notation. What I end up doing was run the compare command, followed by [ $? = 0 ] && ...

Comment: If you want an output as well as the score, change null: to some output image name.suffix.